# Request spec failed on classes nested in module with namespace problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Rspec works fine when I run a single file.
However, I got NameError because I can't get the methods from parent A class when I use `bundle exec rspec` to run all specs.

I checked c.class.ancestors on these two.
I found that B lost namespace A when running all specs.
But B keep namespace A when running single spec file.

Here is my sample code.

```rb
 module A
   class C < B
   end
 end
```

I know I maybe can solve this error if I change the code like this

```rb
 module A
   class C < A::B
   end
 end
```

But I am not sure if it is the correct approach.

Comment: “I got errors” doesn't tell us much. What are the errors?

Comment: If you're trying to ask a question about the difference between the two blocks of sample code you need to edit the title so this doesn't look like a debugging question.

Comment: @coreyward Thank you for your advice. I've added the error type.

Comment: Are you by chance defining multiple `B` classes throughout your test suite?

Comment: Where is B's defination, also paste the directory hierarchy and your stack versions, ruby and rails